# How to "erase all content and settings" on a physical device

Tags: ios, debugging

Since I've got an issue running my app on my physical Iphone 11, I need to relaunch it with all content erased (because if I just erase it and launch it again, I'm still logged in). I'm trying to do the equivalent of "erase all content and settings" of the simulator on my physical device (so that I'm not logged in when I launch it). How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: hi OP.  In your app **Do you use** the iOS Keychain services, yes or no?  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score -1):

Go to

Settings > General > Transfer or Reset iPhone > Erase All Content & Settings.

But this will erase everything and you will have to reactivate your device and restore from backup if applicable.

You should likely rethink your login/logout approach.

Comment: The thing is that it crashed because of a var on the main VC that's nil when it wasnt supposed to, so every time I try to relaunch it, I land on the main VC and it crashes, so I need to launch the app as logged out. But I don't want to erase my whole Iphone, can I avoid that?

Comment: @JOHNY we don’t have any information on that. You need to create a question with all the necessary information needed to reproduce/diagnose your actual issue. Crash reports, what actions cause it, what methods and frameworks are involved. Ideally an Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: As lorem says, it would be absurd to "Erase All Content & Settings" on the actual phone. Don't do that.

Comment: @JOHNY you must have a value held in the keychain that is causing your app to be still logged in. This value will survive an app deletion.  If you know what this value is, you can explicitly delete it in code to "logout". If you don't then erasing the device is the only way to clear it. However, why don't you simply handle the `nil` value correctly in your code. There is no reason your code should crash if you unwrap the optional correctly.

Answer (score -1):

> because if I just erase it and launch it again, I'm still logged in

**You're doing something wrong.**

Erase the app on the phone by **"holding down" until delete appears**.

if you do that **IT WILL completely delete** all user preferences, files or anything else you have done with the app.

GOTCHYA: do you already have ANOTHER COPY of the app (perhaps from the app store or from test flight) on the same phone?

It would be absurd to "Erase All Content & Settings" on the actual phone. Don't do that.

Comment: Deleting the app won't remove values saved in the keychain. Since the OP is still logged in after deleting the app, the login session must be held in the keychain.  Unless they can identify the keychain value in question and explicitly delete the value from the keychain in their app before they delete it, erasing the device is indeed the only way to remove the value.

Comment: @Paulw11 true, TBH I assumed there's no chance the OP was using the keychain. It's very likely OP is just making some simple mistake.

Comment: The behaviour they describe is very common when using logins. Particularly firebase auth.

Comment: @Paulw11 - true enough!